# SQL Server: A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following SQL Server Query in a stored procedure and I am running this service from a windows application. I am populating the temp table variable with 30 million records and then comparing them with previous days records in `tbl_ref_test_main` to Add add and delete the different records. there is a trigger on `tbl_ref_test_main` on insert and delete. Trigger write the same record in another table. Because of the comparison of 30 million records its taking ages to produce the result and throws and error saying `A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.`

Any suggestions please.

Thanks in advance.

```
-- Declare table variable to store the records from CRM database
DECLARE @recordsToUpload TABLE(ClassId NVARCHAR(100), Test_OrdID NVARCHAR(100),Test_RefId NVARCHAR(100),RefCode NVARCHAR(100));

-- Populate the temp table
INSERT INTO @recordsToUpload
SELECT 
class.classid AS ClassId,
class.Test_OrdID AS Test_OrdID ,    
CAST(ref.test_RefId AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Test_RefId, 
ref.ecr_RefCode AS RefCode                  
FROM  Dev_MSCRM.dbo.Class AS class 
LEFT JOIN Dev_MSCRM.dbo.test_ref_class refClass ON refClass.classid = class.classid
LEFT JOIN Dev_MSCRM.dbo.test_ref ref ON refClass.test_RefId = ref.test_RefId
WHERE class.StateCode = 0
AND (ref.ecr_RefCode IS NULL OR (ref.statecode = 0 AND LEN(ref.ecr_RefCode )<= 18 ))                      
AND LEN(class.Test_OrdID )= 12
AND ((ref.ecr_RefCode IS NULL AND ref.test_RefId IS NULL) 
OR (ref.ecr_RefCode IS NOT NULL AND ref.test_RefId IS NOT NULL));                       

-- Insert new records to Main table
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_ref_test_main
Select * from @recordsToUpload 
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_ref_test_main;

-- Delete records from main table where similar records does not exist in temp table
DELETE P FROM dbo.tbl_ref_test_main AS P
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT P.* 
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM @recordsToUpload);

-- Select and return the records to upload
SELECT Test_OrdID,
CASE 
WHEN RefCode IS NULL THEN 'NA' 
ELSE RefCode 
END,
Operation AS 'Operation' 
FROM tbl_daily_upload_records 
ORDER BY Test_OrdID, Operation, RefCode;
```

Comment: the problem most probably occurs in the trigger, did you try debugging it? make sure the column types, sizes of columns and the number of parameters match

Comment: This error message might be a bug in SQL Server because it indicates an unexpected internal state or error. Are there other messages? What does the server log show? Can you run DBCC CHECKDB? Does it print any errors?

Comment: Same application and stored proc I have tested on dev environment where I have just 2500 records. But in pre production I have 30 million records and it throws error there. I don't have access to pre prod so I am unable to run the DBCC CHECKDB there. I have requested the permission and will try that as well.

Comment: @MahaKhairy thanks. I have tested the trigger and it works file.

Comment: @Scorpion you can replace table variable with temp table and try to execute proc statement by statement to find place where error occurs

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be that 30 million rows is too large for the table variable, try creating a temporary table, populating it with the data and then performing the analysis there.
If this isn't possible/suitable then perhaps create a permanent table and truncating it between uses.